# when the firewall prompt popped up I accidently pressed the private networks bubble and now it won't work

Tags: firewall

I've tried a lot of things including going to the control panel then to firewall but I couldn't find it. The only thing I've thought about is clicking reset to default but I don't really know what that'll do. If anyone knows or what I will do please help at least make the message pop up again.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogyrb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open [Windows Firewall](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-10-firewall-4145353).
2. Click on *Inbound Rules* and look for any with a red circle concerning *Google Chrome*. Delete each.
3. Click on *Outbound Rules* and look for any with a red circle concerning *Google Chrome*. Delete each. (there may not be any outbound Chrome rules.)
4. Try running *Google Chrome* again, and **allow** Chrome to make connections.